# AttributeError Django

Tags: python, django

Getting "Generic detail view ItemDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf".

```
 #models.py

class Pic(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('picture:item-detail', kwargs={ 'pk2': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption

 #views.py

class ItemDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Pic
    template_name = 'picture/pic.html'

 #urls.py

urlpatterns = {
    url(r'item/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/$', views.ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='item-detail'),
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be **`pk`** instead of `pk2`, so change your urls config as,

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'item/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='item-detail'),
]
```

The **`url(...)`** likely to be deprecated in a future release., so use [**`re_path()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path)

OR 
You can use [**`path()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path) function as,

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('item/<int:pk>/', views.ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='item-detail'),
]
```